# How to show tooltip of bars as default in highcharts gantt?

Tags: highcharts

I want to show some bars' tooltip as default (not all of them) without hovering on them. is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After chart is loaded, you can use `onMouseOver` point's method to display a tooltip.

```
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function() {
                this.series[0].points[3].onMouseOver();
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dnao0rv6/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#onMouseOver

Comment: Thank you, but when I move the mouse cursor on other points the last popup will be disappeared

Comment: Hi @Meysam Zarei, Highcharts tooltip works in this way. To have a fixed label use annotations. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dnao0rv6/1/